# Initializing global array of function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers, array-initialization

I want to use some evil macro magic to generate an array of pointers to all functions in a file. Unfortunately I'm limited to C99 and not very popular compiler.

I had an idea but I'm not sure if it is safe:

```
void foo(void)
{
    ;    
}

void bar(void)
{
    ;
}

typedef void (*FuncPointer)(void);

FuncPointer array[2] = {foo, bar};
```

I tried it and it compiled and even worked but in C that doesn't actually meen that this kind of thing is safe or portable.

Are there any guarantees about initializaton of global arrays of pointers?

Comment: What does "safe" mean? Does it mean anything? Would you care to define it?

Comment: Sure there are guarantees: If you initialize them, they're initialized. What are your portability concerns? And I'm pretty sure it's impossible to have a macro collect all function names in a file.

Comment: @KerrekSB by "safe" I meant "pointers will be valid"

Comment: Note: could use `FuncPointer array[] = {foo, bar};`.

Comment: @Amomum: Then why don't you just say that?

Comment: @KerrekSB my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed to work by the standard. All such arrays are filled in before `main` is called.

Additionally, this is guaranteed to be finished before any global constructors are called, if you are using C++ or compiler-specific extensions that support global constructors in C (e.g. `__attribute__((constructor))` in GNU C.)

The only case you might have to worry about is if you're writing your own kernel, in which case you have to take care of loading all parts of the executable.

Comment: Would it change anything if I declare all functions and array as static?